# Format converion of different wide formats

Tags: r

I have some genes for each of them I have how many clonal or sub-clonal mutations they have like below

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  gene_name clonal subclonal
  <chr>      <int>     <int>
1 APC            3         1
2 ARID1A         5         2
3 ARID1B        18         7
4 ARID2         16         2
5 CCDC102B     100        30
6 CCND1          2         0
>
```

For each gene for instance APC I want something like below

[image]

Is there anyway to do this in R?

Thank you so much

Comment: APC is a gene for which we have 3 clonal mutations and 1 subclonal mutation

Comment: Yes exactly that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option where we reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then expand the rows based on the numeric count in 'value' column, and create the `Yes_no` from checking whether the 'Clonality' value is 'clonal'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = clonal:subclonal, names_to = 'Clonality') %>% 
  uncount(value) %>% 
  mutate(Yes_no = case_when(Clonality == 'clonal' ~ 'Yes', TRUE ~ 'No'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 186 x 3
#   gene_name Clonality Yes_no
#   <chr>     <chr>     <chr> 
# 1 APC       clonal    Yes   
# 2 APC       clonal    Yes   
# 3 APC       clonal    Yes   
# 4 APC       subclonal No    
# 5 ARID1A    clonal    Yes   
# 6 ARID1A    clonal    Yes   
# 7 ARID1A    clonal    Yes   
# 8 ARID1A    clonal    Yes   
# 9 ARID1A    clonal    Yes   
#10 ARID1A    subclonal No    
# … with 176 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene_name = c("APC", "ARID1A", "ARID1B", "ARID2", 
"CCDC102B", "CCND1"), clonal = c(3L, 5L, 18L, 16L, 100L, 2L), 
    subclonal = c(1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 30L, 0L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```